# Close button on alert not working with Bootstrap & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get following code to work in my MVC 5 project:

```html
<!-- for the snippet to work -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<p>This alert should close, when clicking the 'x'-button:</p>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

I took it from the [official bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts). The alert should close, when the 'x'-button is clicked. As you can see, it actually works fine in this snippet. However it doesn't in my application. The alert does simply not close. Obviously the MVC framework must be responsible for this somehow.

The brower's debug console does not display any error messages. And yes, I also included the JS sources for Bootstrap (3.5.5) and jQuery (2.1.4) in the project - They are loaded properly and displayed under 'sources' in the browser's debug view.

**EDIT**: Aaron suggested that some other script might overwrite/shadow the bootstrap code. So these are the js libraries my project currently uses:

- jquery-2.1.4.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js
- jquery.effects.highlight.min.js
- jquery.effects.core.min.js
- plus some other hand written helper js with helper methods

They are loaded in the same order as listed. Omitting following libraries did not help:

- jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js
- jquery.effects.highlight.min.js
- jquery.effects.core.min.js

Removing the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` causes my application to "crash", since it cannot load content dynamically anymore.

Following anonymous function declaration is called, when the document is loaded (**before** the alert has been dynamically inserted into the html):

```
Alert.prototype.close = function (e) {...}
```

Clicking the 'x'-button does not seem to call any code from the bootstrap.js, but maybe I just did not find the right spot to put the breakpoint on.

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, jsfiddle and bootply worked as well

Comment: Well, it only happens in your participial project. You need to strip out all JavaScripts and re-put them back one at a time.

Comment: Also you should make sure that none of the javascript libraries are being loaded more than once.

Comment: @DavidTansey I just checked the resulting full html file and there are no duplicate references

Comment: Try checking in the chrome debugger if the close function is even hit. In the bootstrap.js file I found this which appears to be the close functionality.  If it is not being hit then their may be something overriding it.                                                                             d.prototype.close = function(b) {
        function c() {
            g.detach().trigger("closed.bs.alert").remove()
        }

Comment: Also ASP.NET MVC may be loading jquery as well. Take a look at the Network tab on chrome and ensure the order of the js files being loaded. Maybe jquery is being loaded twice.

Comment: @Aaron I could not find the function you mentioned. The only method, which contains `'closed.bs.alert'` is `removeElement()` and the breakpoint does not hit. Neither does it on a line, which contains `Alert.prototype.close = function (e) {`. I checked the network tab and everthing is loaded exactly once from my project's directory. I will edit my question and add a list of js libraries, which I also included to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, but I'm not quite sure what the actual reason for this issue was. Here is what I did:

1. Delete all local bootstrap sources (initially downloaded via nuget)
2. Use the remote sources instead (as in the snippet)

Afterwards the alert closed properly as it is supposed to. Strangely the problem does not occur anymore if I reinstall the bootstrap sources from nuget and use them instead of the remote ones. The other scripts I mentioned do not seem to conflict with bootstrap or jquery, since I'm still using them. I also did *not* change the loading order.

I must have either corrupted the local bootstrap sources unintentionally *or* there must have been an error in a previous version of the bootstrap nuget package. Maybe there has been more than one package for the same bootstrap version. I think that caching issues can be excluded, since I did not actually change anything besides reinstalling the sources.

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle included worked fine for me. I would suggest opening chrome developer tools (hit `ctrl+shift+j`) to debug.

Possible issues:

You could have a proxy/firewall blocking the CDN so your JS doesn't load. That would show in the network tab in developer tools. Try loading the bootstrap js file locally.

Alternatively, there are conflicting versions of javascript. You'll see an error pop up in the console tab of the developer tools.

Comment: I have all sources located on my machine, which runs the MVC application, so I would exclude any networking issues. The network tab does not reveal anything suspicious, everthing returns a HTTP 200 OK. The console tab stays clear all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mentioned that these are the libraries you are using:

- jquery-2.1.4.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js

Is this also the order they are loading in? If so then it looks like close() might be getting overridden by close() in jqueryUI because jqueryUI is loaded after bootstrap.

Comment: This is not the case: As I already said, they ARE loaded in this certain order, BUT if I remove `jquery-ui`, `jquery.effects.highlight` and `jquery.effects.core`  the problem still exists.